# An I/O error occured while sending to the backend

Tags: java, jdbc

I started using postgreSQL server for my project. This is my first time using it. I have used other commercial relational db servers and mysql before, but I haven't had many issues.  I have a java application which is spring-based and multi-threaded. I am using the postgreSQL jdbc 9 version.

This is spring config for datasource.

```
    <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClass}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${tribune.jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${tribune.jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${tribune.jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="20"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="40"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="1"/>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="20"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select version()"/>
</bean>
```

when I run my application, I see two frequent issues.

1. org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 1 for update statement for pstmt.setString(1, variable); I check the variable to see if it's empty or null before this line. But it still happens.

   ```
       if (programId == null || programId.isEmpty()) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("'programId' can not be null.");
   }
   Connection conn = null;
   PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   SubscriptionGroup subscriptionGroup = new SubscriptionGroup();

   conn = session.getConnection();
   String query = getQuery(QUERY_GET_NOTIFICATIONS_BY_PROGRAM_ID);
   log.debug("getSubscriptionGroupByProgramId.query: " + query);
   log.info("getSubscriptionGroupByProgramId.programId: " + programId + "=="+ programId.length());
   pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
   pstmt.setString(1, programId);
   rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
   ```

An exception is thrown from 'rs = pstmt.executeQuery()'.

1. Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occured while sending to the backend.
   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:283)
   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.executeTransactionCommand(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:685)
   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.commit(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:709)
   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:301)
   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:301)
   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.commit(PoolingDataSource.java:200)

For #2, It happens when it tries to commit even though it didn't failing in getting statement from the connection.

could anybody (who has used postgreSQL or familiar with the datasource setting) tell me what the problem is?

Thanks.

Comment: Point 1 could be a bug in your program but can't be certain without seeing your code. Which Jdbc driver are you using? I allways use the jdbc4 driver located here: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html Have the feeling from your stack trace that you have a rather old one.

Comment: You've omitted the actual SQL query.